# How can i rotate an image in SwiftUI with one finger only?

Tags: swiftui, rotation, uiimage

I have an image in a view and i want to be able to rotate it with one finger only, how can i do that in SwiftUI?

I checked the RotationGesture but it works only with two fingers...

Thanks

Comment: how much you want to rotate this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i got it with this code :
https://gist.github.com/ts95/9f8e05380824c6ca999ab3bc1ff8541f

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed it with this code :

```
struct RotationGesture: View {
    @State var totalRotation = CGSize.zero
    @State var currentRotation = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(-totalRotation.width)))
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        totalRotation.width = value.translation.width + currentRotation.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        currentRotation = totalRotation
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

But now we have to fixed the vertical movement because this solution is only working when you move around the X axis...

I want to solution to work when you make circle movement around the view you want to rotate...

Answer (score 0):

one finger rotation

```
struct RotationGesture: View {
        @State var gestureValue = CGSize.zero
        var body: some View {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.orange)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(-gestureValue.width)))
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged({ (value) in
                        self.gestureValue = value.translation
                    }).onEnded({ (value) in
                        self.gestureValue = .zero
                    })
                )
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ufuk, it's a very good start but it doesn't rotate perfectly when you move around...  Also, when you start next rotation it's doesn't keep the previous rotation...

Comment: how exactly do you want it to act? Do you want your position not to be reset when you end the rotation movement?

Comment: With circle movement around the view you want to rotate. Clockwise or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solutions from above this is what I have for rotating with one finger. This will keep the position when you finish rotating as well as starting the next rotation where the last one left off.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State private var rotation: Angle = Angle(degrees: 0)
    @State private var previousRotation: Angle?
    

    var body: some View {
      
            Circle()
                .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), center: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, angle: .degrees(90)))
                .frame(width: 760, height: 760)
                .rotationEffect(rotation, anchor: .center)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged{ value in
                        if let previousRotation = self.previousRotation {
                            let deltaY = value.location.y - (760 / 2)
                            let deltaX = value.location.x - (760 / 2)
                            let fingerAngle = Angle(radians: Double(atan2(deltaY, deltaX)))
                            
                            let angle = fingerAngle - previousRotation
                            rotation += angle
                            self.previousRotation = fingerAngle
                            
                        } else {
                            let deltaY = value.location.y - (760 / 2)
                            let deltaX = value.location.x - (760 / 2)
                            let fingerAngle = Angle(radians: Double(atan2(deltaY, deltaX)))
                            previousRotation = fingerAngle
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded{ _ in
                        previousRotation = nil
                    })

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A `dragGesture` will give us the value of a location where user has dragged on screen (in our case, the circle). Here, the circle frame will be equal height and equal width.

Capturing the location point where the user tapped and subtracting `height/`2 from `y` point and `width/2` from `x` point results in `deltaX` and `deltaY`. Once we have `deltaX` and `deltaY`, we can convert it into radians using the `atan2` function (which is provided by the Swift Standard Library).

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State var angle: Angle = .zero
    var circleFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), center: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, angle: .degrees(90)))
            .padding()
            .rotationEffect(angle)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let deltaY = value.location.y - (circleFrame.height / 2)
                        let deltaX = value.location.x - (circleFrame.width / 2)
                        angle = Angle(radians: Double(atan2(deltaY, deltaX)))  
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers that only consist of code with no explanation are not as useful as they could be. Mind [edit]ing your answer to add a bit of explanation about how the code works and how it will solve the problem?